# How are these classes able to access the default package (post-compile)?

Tags: java

This is taken from the *bytecode* of Minecraft.  Most of the jar's classes are found in the default package, however there is another package, "net.minecraft.client", which has the main class (Minecraft.class) that runs the game loop, sets up OpenGL, etc.  I don't have the source, but if I open up Minecraft.class in JD-Gui, it has the following import setup:

```
package net.minecraft.client;

import aaa;
import aai;
import ajq;
import ajv;
import akf;
import aki;
import aqx;
import aqz;
import ara;
import arb;
... (many more classes from the default package)

public abstract class Minecraft implements Runnable, mc {
...
}
```

How does this work?  Let's say I have a folder with a similar setup (default classes that need to be accessed by other packages) and want to compile it with a batch file.  What method of compiling could replicate this result?

Answer (score 3):

> This is taken from the source of Minecraft.

I don't think so. (EDIT: The question was edited to make this "bytecode" - which doesn't make much sense, as bytecode isn't Java source code. Anyway...)

> How does this work?

It doesn't, fundamentally. The code you're looking at in JD-Gui isn't the original source code - it's code which represents the bytecode as accurately as JD-Gui is able to manage.

I strongly suspect the original source code *does* use packages, but then uses an obfuscator of some kind to rename the classes and put them in the default package. I strongly suspect this isn't the only kind of change which leaves valid bytecode which couldn't actually be directly compiled from valid source code. (For example, I strongly suspect there are method names which are valid in bytecode but not in source code.)

> Let's say I have a folder with a similar setup (default classes that need to be accessed by other packages) and want to compile it with a batch file. What method of compiling could replicate this result?

You wouldn't. You'd have source code set up using packages (as all sane, non-trivial Java code does), compile it and then post-process the bytecode.

Comment: Sorry about my bad terminology.  Is there a way to alter compiled code easily?

Comment: @JeffDemanche: There are obfuscators, there are libraries such as BCEL. But it's not clear what you're really trying to *achieve*, or why.